# Mobile paginated search results broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, mobile

On the mobile site, Safari on iPhone

https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=test

Clicking on the page 2 button or next button takes me to

`https://english.stackexchange.com/search?page=2&amp;tab=Relevance&amp;pagesize=15&amp;q=test`

which is just a blank search page

Looks like the & is being double-HTML-entitied. Only tested on English and Stackoverflow, worked fine on the latter but not the former.

Comment: Well... now the site is refixing that link so it works. Replace all & with & amp;

Comment: Andrew, is my edit what you see? (I don't see double HTML entities, which is why I ask.)

Comment: @Martha yes, thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next deploy.